# How to use DebugDiag now that Internet Explorer is deprecated?

Tags: .net, windows, internet-explorer, debugdiag

DebugDiag generates its results and displays them using Internet Explorer.  Specifically, its using ActiveX controls for display and navigation. However, my Internet Explorer has been disabled, either by a Windows update or perhaps corporate policy (not sure).

How can I use DebugDiag going forward without the Internet Explorer? I haven't seen an update.  Is there a replacement?

Specifically I am trying to see the stack trace of a crashed .NET Framework 4.61 process.

P.S. My solution for now is to use a box that hasn't been updated yet, but it's not really a solution.

Comment: IE might be dead but I assume other apps can still embed the mshtml control? I don't know if Maxton (or whatever the other IE browsers were called) can be dropped in to replace iexplore.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean open the generated `.mht` report file? If so, you can open the file using [Edge IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality). Edge IE mode supports ActiveX controls.

You need to enable IE 11 in Windows Features, then you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list) to load the site in Edge IE mode.